# The macros setmainfont and setsansfont do not accept the new command of a newfontfamily. Is there compatibility between them?

Tags: fonts, xetex, memoir, fontspec, mac

I use the class `memoir`, the packages `polyglossia`, `fontspec`, compile in XeLaTeX in Linux and on macOS.

Based on [XeTeX package fontspec: Use previously defined \newfontfamily with \setmainfont](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29457/xetex-package-fontspec-use-previously-defined-newfontfamily-with-setmainfont) (there were not available answers to this), I would like to set an extra font coming from a new command of `newfontfamily` to `setmainfont` and `setsansfont` because I find unnecessary to multiply the same path/localization of the fonts in each macro. I want to economise and optimise the codes. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands, dvipsname]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\alegreya{Alegreya}[Path = ./fontes/,
  FontFace = {xb}{n}  {* Black},
  FontFace = {xb}{it} {* Black Italic},
  UprightFont = * Regular,
  ItalicFont = * Regular Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
]

\setmainfont{\alegreya}
\setsansfont{\alegreya}
```

Only my `newfontfamily` part works, but the `set*font` does accept the defined newcommand.

Comment: That won't work. Create a fontspec-file if you want to reuse font settings, see section 2.3 By custom file name in the fontspec documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by assigning the family name. The string is essentially arbitrary, so long as it doesn't refer to an existing font family.

(I had to adapt the font setup to my machine.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\alegreya{Alegreya}[
  %Path = ./fontes/,
  FontFace = {xb}{n}  {*-Black},
  FontFace = {xb}{it} {*-BlackItalic},
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  NFSSFamily=alegreyaot
]

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{alegreyaot}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{alegreyaot}

\begin{document}

This should be Alegreya

\textsf{This too}

{\normalfont\alegreya Check}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, I also have tested fontspec-file as Ulrike has suggested and it worked too. But what is the renewcommand for default maths font, similar to setmathsfont: mathnormal, mathrm or mathsf?

Comment: @GustavoReis Since there is no math font compatible with Alegreya, I'd not bother. But `\setmathrm{Alegreya-Regular}` should work.

Comment: Then I will use Charter BT Math or GFS Neohellenic Math or Linux Libertinus Math.