# Using JetBrainsMono as main font in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use JetBrainsMono as the main font for beamer. I am using `xelatex` to compile the document and it seems to recognize the font but the font is not applied to the document.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newfontfamily{\jtbmedium}{JetBrainsMono-Medium}[
Path            =/home/dbarcene/.fonts/,
Extension       =.ttf,
Ligatures       =TeX]

\newfontfamily{\jtbbold}{JetBrainsMono-Bold}[
Path            =/home/dbarcene/.fonts/,
Extension       =.ttf,
Ligatures       =TeX]

\setmainfont{\jtbmedium}

\title{Long Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date\today

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{First Frame}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What would be the proper procedure to use system fonts like `JetBrainsMono` in beamer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer uses sans serif text, you have to use `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmainfont` (or use a serif font theme instead)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex 

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\setsansfont{JetBrains Mono}

\title{Long Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date\today

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{First Frame}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Using your newly defined font families in `\setsansfont` doesn't work, so I'm using the font there directly, see [The macros setmainfont and setsansfont do not accept the new command of a newfontfamily. Is there compatibility between them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462544/the-macros-setmainfont-and-setsansfont-do-not-accept-the-new-command-of-a-newfon) for details)